# Numpy math with arrays and scalars?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, normalization

Numpy newbie here. I'm trying to normalize (aka feature scaling, standardization) my inputs to a neural network.  I just doing linear scaling and the formula I'm using is:

`I = Imin + (Imax-Imin)*(D-Dmin)/(Dmax-Dmin)`

where I is the scaled input value, Imin and Imax are the desired min and max range of the scaled values, D is the original data value, and Dmin and Dmax are the min and max range of the original data values.  I want a python method that takes a numpy array and returns an array with all the values normalized.  This is what I'm thinking so far.

```
def get_normalized_values(array):
    """I = Imin + (Imax-Imin)*(D-Dmin)/(Dmax-Dmin)"""
    imin = -1
    imax = 1
    dmin = array.amin()
    dmax = array.amax()

    normalized = imin + (imax - imin)*(array - dmin)/(dmax - dmin)

    return normalized
```

My question is will this work?  Or do I have to loop through each element in the array and perform the math?  Can you just do math like this with arrays and scalars?  That is, will `array - dmin` create a new temporary array where each value has dmin subtracted?  Not sure if this is the right terminology but I think this is a "vectorized" approach?

**Update**

Is there a way to have this modify the array in place?  That is rather than returning a copy of the array, have the function take the array and modify the original array?

Comment: Things like this normally work fine, do just try it.  One thing is that amin and amax should just be min and max.  Or argmin/argmax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you need to change the calls `amin()` and `amax()` to just be calls to `min()` and `max()`, as in `my_array.max()`.

Otherwise, this should work fine. You can do things in NumPy much like Octave/Matlab, such as adding a scalar to an array, and it automatically knows to map the operation to all elements. Sometimes, you might need slightly different syntax (like knowing the difference between `numpy.linalg.dot()` and just multiplying two arrays), but in general things like this are as straightforward as you have indicated.

Comment: What's the difference between amin, amax and min, max?

Comment: I don't believe that `amin()` is a member function of array types in NumPy. I'm pretty sure you use `numpy.amin()` to compute a minimum along an axis, and that `my_array.amin()` will throw an error (it definitely throws an error for me in NumPy 1.5.1 when I test your code above). The proper method that is implemented for array types is the `min()` method, such as `my_array.min()`. So you can choose to call `amin` if you want, but you can't call it with the dot-syntax after the array's name.

Comment: Also, there's a small personal aesthetic preference. I use the NumPy function `argmin()` often to get the index of a minimum entry. And I don't like the potential confusion of `min`, `argmin` and `amin`. I tend to only use things that are class methods for the array types, and I avoid any array operation that is applied by calling `np.some_function(array)`. I try to stick to `array.some_function()`, and there is no such thing for `amin()`, it can only be called as `np.amin(array)`.

Comment: That's because I modified my question and was hoping for an answer on the edit.  But instead I decided to open a new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149416/numpy-modify-array-in-place

Answer (score 2):

It's python - just try it (tm)

I really don't know the answer, but my way of finding out would be to paste the question into an iPython terminal session.  Generally whenever I have wondered how to do something like this in numby the simple way has worked.